# UISearchController like Instagram Explore Tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

In the Instagram app, the explore feed comprises of a default view which is a UICollectionView. Once the search bar that is located in the navigation bar is tapped the "search display table view" is displayed and the user can search for users or hashtags. How can I accomplish this? As of right now I have a UICollectionViewController working fine and a search bar in the navigation bar but now I need to implement the table view to show up once the search bar is tapped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I worked on something similar. The best way to approach this for me was to have a different view controller for search results and when I clicked on the search bar I would navigate to the search View Controller without animation. and when the cancel button on search View controller is pressed I would navigate back to the collection view controller. All the searching algorithms can be handled in the Search View Controller and it could be a table view. Hope this helps.